# Downloading Sentinel images from Copernicus Scihub?

Tags: sentinel-1, copernicus

I've been trying to download a Sentinel-1B image from Copernicus off and on for a couple weeks. I can never get the download to complete; in fact, it rarely gets about a couple percent. I've tested my internet connection and download speeds, and also tried at different times during the day/night. I think the issue might be on their end.

If anyone else is having difficulty downloading from Scihub, is there an alternative source for free Sentinel images?

Comment: What software/process are you using?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the same scene from different source ie: https://vertex.daac.asf.alaska.edu/#

Comment: Have you considered using Python for this? Providing you have a log in for the Scihub, there is a great API called Sentinelsat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the Python API for this. Especially if you wish to download a lot of data, as it automates the process, unlike the Scihub. You're able to define an AOI as a geojson, and type in the parameters you need, and download.

This is some code I have previously used:

#First, import this library (sentinelsat)
    from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt

```
#Enter your username and password
api = SentinelAPI("USER", "PASSWORD", "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus")

#Define the path to your AOI - Must be a Geojson shapefile
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson(r"path/to/AOI.geojson"))
#Define the products you need - Here you will be looking for Ground Range detected products, with a Descending orbit direction from 01/05/2019 to 01/06/2019 
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20190501','20190601'),
                     producttype = 'GRD',
                     orbitdirection='DESCENDING')
#Download all products 
api.download_all(products)
```

If you're looking for countrywide data, split the AOI up into smaller shapefiles (Either for the Sentinelsat Python AOI, or on the Sci-hub as i had this issue where it returned no results if my AOI was too large.

Have a read of this for more info:
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/sentinelsat/master/sentinelsat.pdf

Otherwise, https://www.asf.alaska.edu/sentinel/ is useful.

Answer (score 2):

To download radar products such as sentinel 1 I would recommend Alaska satellite facility.

https://search.asf.alaska.edu/#/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Scihub; I emailed them and received the response below. The above answers/comments by others are helpful alternatives.

[image]